# CSS animation duration bug in IE10

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-10, css-animations

I'm using the Bootstrap animated progress bars in a project but I've come across a bug with the animation in IE10.  When the page renders the width of the progress bar is 10% and then after 5 seconds the width increases to 100%.  The default duration time of the animation is 2 seconds but when the width is increased the duration of the animation isn't scaled so effectively the animation speed increases 10 time.

I've put together a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a224hd49/1/) to demonstrate what I mean.  Is there a way to keep the animation speed proportionate to the width in IE?

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%"><span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $(".progress-bar").delay(2000).animate({"width": "100%"});
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the duration of the animation isn't scaled"

Comment: This is not a bootstrap bug. The issue here is delay != duration. Delay is the amount of time that must pass before the animation begins. Duration is how long the animation takes to complete.

Answer (score 3):

You can overwrite bootstrap css by this:

```
@keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 -40px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### the issue

It is not really clear how this can be an animation duration bug specific to IE10, because the very fact of specifying a duration for your animation means that it won't be proportionate to the "distance" the progress bar has to travel.

> Unless of course you are referring to the striped animation? If you are referring to this, then fixing the issues I raise below (i.e. not animating with both CSS and JS) may help, if not you can still apply the same idea but rather than overriding **`transition`**, you can override **`animation-duration`** instead and still base the duration on the progress bar's width. I wasn't able to reproduce this issue however.

The fact that your demo is using both jQuery and CSS transitions simultaneously may lead to weird effects in IE10, as it does in other browsers.

### possible solution

If I understand what you are trying to achieve, all you need do is lengthen the duration depending on the dimensional size of your progress bar's parent. You can do this — overriding the Bootstrap CSS — like so. I include two bars to show that they do not complete at the same time, but should have similar pace:

Breaking the code into the `runbars` function and wrapping in a `setTimeout` are just to replicate your `5000` delay, and to give a pause before the code actually runs; they aren't needed for the code to actually work. However, you will need to use `$.each` if you have more than one progress bar on the page at any one time.

> If you are referring to the striped animation, just switch out **`transition`** below and replace with **`animation-duration`**. The only issue with resetting the animation duration once is that you may find now that the animation is very slow when only at, say **10%**. However, if you are actually programatically updating the progress bar as and when things progress (which would make sense), you can update the animation duration based on the current percent of the bar that is complete. So instead of just using **`bar.parent()`** you would use **`bar.parent()/100*percentage_calculate`**.

```js
$(function() {
  var runbars = function(){
    $(".progress-bar")
      .each(function(i, elm){
        var bar = $(elm);
        bar.css({
          'transition': 'width '+ (bar.parent().width()/200)+'s linear 0s',
          'width': '100%'
        });
      })
    ;
  };
  setTimeout(runbars, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="progress" style="width: 50%;">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" 
       role="progressbar" 
       aria-valuenow="10" 
       aria-valuemin="0" 
       aria-valuemax="100" 
  ><span class="sr-only">10% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" 
       role="progressbar" 
       aria-valuenow="10" 
       aria-valuemin="0" 
       aria-valuemax="100" 
   ><span class="sr-only">10% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

### take note

The equation `bar.parent().width()/200` can be read as `number of seconds to travel per every 200 pixels`, which means the "traveling" rate will always be the same no matter how many pixels are involved.

Also notice that I'm not using `$.animate`, all I am doing is setting the width of the progress bar to 100%, setting the transition time relative to the progress bar size (via jQuery) and then leaving the CSS transitions to do the work. Your fiddle is actually using jQuery to animate the bar, whilst the browser is also trying to transition the bar using CSS. You should chose one way of doing things or the other.

> It's worth noting that in my example above I am only using the unprefixed version of `transition` or `animation-duration`. To cater for as many browsers as possible you should also implement browser vendor prefix alternatives. Doing so from JavaScript can be a bit tricky, but [this post](http://davidwalsh.name/vendor-prefix) is a good example on how to detect the right prefix to use. *For the most part most modern browsers should support an unprefixed transition/animation, but you can never guarantee that everyone has upgraded*